# Адаптивный блок с 4 картинками на Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы блок с четырьмя картинками адаптировался под разные размеры экрана. Почти все сделал, но заметил проблему: при размере страницы больше 976px, три картинки остаются сверху, а одна остается снизу. Я понимаю, что это связано с размером самих картинок. Но все они разных размеров, из-за этого я придумал только один способ, который подгоняет их все под один определенный размер (Только они кажутся после этого достаточно большими, буду благодарен, если кто-то предложит вариант с их уменьшением). Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему? Я сам пока только про использование медиа-запроса для этого размера думаю.

```css
.recommend-list{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  justify-content: center;
}

.recommend-book img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.recommend-book{
  margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recommend-list">
<div class="recommend-book">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://knigomania.org/_ld/3/87049286.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="recommend-book">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://knigomania.org/_ld/3/09115516.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="recommend-book">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://knigomania.org/_ld/1/50372781.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="recommend-book">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://knigomania.org/_ld/1/36317514.jpg"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Решается добавлением элемента с классом, например, .line-break {  width: 100%;} . На больших разрешениях экрана он нулевой ширины, а на тех, где требуется перенос нужного количества элементов - .line-break {  width: 100%;} Или просто элемент break {display: написать нужное для нужных медиа-запросов;}

Comment: @Наталья а можно пример?

Comment: @Наталья Мне удалось их в ряд выстроить, добавив медиа-запрос (min-width:976px) и задав ширину .recommend-book в 22%. Нормальное решение, или Ваш вариант будет рациональнее?)

Comment: Я думаю, нормальное. Почему, нет? Главное, что Ваши задачи решены понятным и удобным Вам способом. Если еще нужен пример, посмотрите здесь: https://baseflat.ru/ Меню-картинками. Стили в этом файле: view-source:https://baseflat.ru/style_new.css                           Я, правда, для самых больших экранов его не адаптировала (от 1900 px... и шире), - нет смысла для 0,5% юзеров сражаться за то, чтобы по 3 элемента переносить. Фиг с ним, что один смещается

Comment: Смотрите после комментария <!-- Стили для меню картинками-->